# How does Chrome handle image loading during a request animation frame?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a custom mapping system that works with image tiles similar to how the popular mapping systems work from google, bing, yahoo, etc.

My first implementation worked fine but panned the map on the cycle of the mouse events, i.e., when a mouse drag came in it would reposition the map.  This worked but was a bit jittery.  I happened to use "request animation frame" for another project and it worked well and thought I'd change my map to use it.

It was a relatively simple fix to divorce the mouse events from the map updates and instead update using animation frames and it is noticeably smoother.  However, I notice in Chrome when I'm panning the map around the image tiles don't load in until I'm done panning.  As soon as I stop moving the mouse the images load.  Note I don't even have to release the mouse button but just stop the mouse movement. And this definitely isn't a cacheing issue as it'll happen even when all of the images have been previously loaded.

However, if I open the map in Firefox or Safari the images load correctly as expected.

So I'm just hoping I'm missing something here and there's an easy fix. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the major map vendors but maybe they're not using rAF?

Thanks!

Comment: A link to the page and some relevant code could be helpful.

Comment: @shikkediel: Yeah, I should have mentioned this.  I can't share the page and it's way too complicated for simple review.  I could try and reproduce with a small example, but I was hoping somebody had already seen this and had quick advice.  If not, yeah, I'll have to create a small example to share.  Thanks!